# Centralizar um plot em cima de uma imagem no Matlab

Tags: plot, matlab

Estou plotando em cima de uma imagem, contudo com o código abaixo o plot acontece no início da imagem em 0,0. Gostaria de que fosse feito a partir do centro da imagem em questão.
Trecho do código:

```
image=imread('imagem.jpg');
imshow(image);
hold on;
plot(X,Y,'k-','linewidth',2)
hold off;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode mover o local onde a imagem será desenhada definindo `XData` e `YData` em `imshow`. Para centralizar, você define que a posição da imagem (por padrão é [0,0]) é [-largura/2, -altura/2].

**Exemplo**

```
% carrega a imagem
image=imread('imagem.jpg');

% calcula a metade da altura e largura
image_sz = size(image) * 0.5;

% desenha a imagem deslocada
imshow(image, 'XData', [-image_sz(1) image_sz(1)],'YData', [-image_sz(2) image_sz(2)]);
hold on;
```

---

**Demontração**

Para a seguinte imagem:

[image: Imagem de Exemplo]

E essa função:

```
t = 0:0.0001:2*pi;
x = 50 * cos(t);
y = 50 * sin(t);
plot(x,y)
```

Centralizando a imagem, você tem:

[image: Resultado]

---

Para centralizar a função à imagem você pode simplesmente deslocar os elementos da função ao centro da imagem. Por exemplo:

Para essa função:

```
t = 0:0.0001:2*pi;
x = 50 * cos(t);
y = 50 * sin(t);
```

Desloque usando:

```
x = x + image_sz(1);
y = y + image_sz(2);
```

O que resulta em:

[image: Outro resultado.]

Comment: O plot é que precisa ser centralizado não a imagem.

Comment: Então é só deslocar os elementos da função. Mas, eu acho deslocar a imagem mais eficiente.

Comment: Considerei certa porque resolveu de outra forma, mas no meu caso isto não é possível tive que deslocar a função como comentou.